# PropertyChanged for a custom class is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and binding, I watched dozen questions here, but problem still exists.

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DAA.IST.ChoosePC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DAA.IST.ChoosePC"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Question x:Key="ExpertSystem" Text="question"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ExpertSystem}">
    <Label x:Name="Description" Content="Определение опимальной конфигурации ПК" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="QuestionLable" Content="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="Result" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

I list here full code, because I really don't know there problem is, sorry. Main window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static IQuestion Question;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Question = new Question
        {
            Text = "question",
            Answers = new List<IAnswer>
                      {
                          new Answer {Text = "answer", NextQuestionNumber = 0},
                          new Answer {Text = "answer1", NextQuestionNumber = 0}
                      }
        };
        DataContext = Question;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Question.Answer(0);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Question.Answer(1);
    }
}
```

And `Question`code, this class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Question : IQuestion, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }


    public IList<IAnswer> Answers { get; set; }

    public void Answer(int number)
    {
        MainWindow.Question.Answers[number].Number = number;
        MainWindow.Question.Answers[number].SetNextQuestion();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Please help me, sure I miss or don't know something. Also if someone can give me advise about changing of `IList<IAnswer> Answers`, I will be thankful to him^^

Comment: you have added all the code but your question is not clear. What problem exactly, you are facing?

Comment: I need to change content of label and two buttons from `Question` class. As I understand best way is binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but `PropertyChanged` is always null

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is bad practice to refer MainWindow inside your question class.
You should use commands in this context i.e. you should define a command in your DataContext( question here) and bind that Command to your two Button's Command property.

For example:

```
Class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged, IQuestion
{
  public ICommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set;}

  public Question()
  {
    //Bind ButtonClickCommand to Event Handler/ A Method
    ButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(EventHandlerName);
  }
  public void EventHandlerName()
  {
  }
}
```

Also, take a private _answers field in the class and raise **OnPropertyChanged** event from Setter of Answers property too, to utilize this list in Notification mechanism i.e.

```
public IList<IAnswer> Answers { 
  get { return _answers }
  set { _nswers = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("Answers");
```

}

And, you have mentioned that you want to chnge the content of label and buttons. But to change the content of label and Buttons, you need to bind the 'Content' of these controls to Properties in Question class as well. I don't see any binding in your XAML as of now.

Comment: Because I don't bind buttons yet, but but label is binded.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found my mistake. I should change property, not create new instances. If I create new one, old value remains the same. It is connected with reference types realization some way.

```
MainWindow.Question.Text = "question";
MainWindow.Question.Answers[0].Text = "answer0";
MainWindow.Question.Answers[0].NextQuestionNumber = number0;
MainWindow.Question.Answers[1].Text = "answer1";
MainWindow.Question.Answers[1].NextQuestionNumber = number1;
```

Comment: You aren't raising `PropertyChanged` in the setter for `Answers`. You need to raise `PropertyChanged` in the setter for `Answers`. It's hard to be sure since you were so unclear about what the problem is, but @RohitGarg probably answered your question.